# Entering Alphanumeric value from Access to textbox - VBScript - Powerbuilder

Tags: automation, vbscript, powerbuilder, hp-uft

I'm attempting to enter a NI number into a Powerbuilder application from an Access DB.
Whenever I attempt to enter "AA123456A" into my application, UFT passes the value in as 123456.

```vb
If f_GetAccessFieldValue("NINumber") <> "" Then
    PbWindow("w_genapp_frame").PbWindow("Client Details").PbDataWindow("dw_ap010_03_02"). SetCellData "#1","custp_ni_code",f_GetAccessFieldValue("NINumber")
End If
```

The value from Access is definitely passed in as a string.

Is this a limitation of my application, or is there a simple way to fix this without having to split the string and enter the values using separated variables?

Edit: Just noticed that even sending letters on their own ("AA") does not work.

Comment: What does the value of `f_GetAccessFieldValue("NINumber")` contain? Have you confirmed the expected result is coming from `f_GetAccessFieldValue("NINumber")` before you then try passing into the Powerbuilder app?

Comment: @user692942 It returns AA123456 (string)

Comment: Well, chances are then that the cell in the SAPGuiGrid doesn't match what you are expecting, according to the [official documentation for `SetCellData()`](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/15.0-15.0.2/UFT_Help/Subsystems/OMRHelp/Content/mySAP-Windows/SAPGUIPACKAGELib~SAPGuiGrid.html#SetCellData) - "The possible values for the data **depends on the type of cell**. For example, the values may be "ON" or "OFF" for a check box or radio button cell, or may be limited to the available values of a combo box."

Comment: @user692942 It must be the way in which VB Script interacts with my application or PowerBuilder. I've tried using WshShell.SendKeys to send "AA123456A" which works fine. But I need to be able to pass this value in from the DB so Send Keys is no good

Comment: Try and split it. Try a combination of `.Selectcell  "#1","custp_ni_code"` and then `.type f_GetAccessFieldValue("NINumber")`

Comment: If `.selectcell` isn't right, try `.activatecell`  - there's no known limitations for this in the docs so it might just need some additional trickery

Comment: Seems strange behaviour, to be honest. But, I can't see how it's a VBScript issue.

Comment: Hi @RichEdwards , I've found a solution that isn't 100% ideal but it works. I've set the Access value to a variable and then sent that variable through SendKeys, which now works. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to use SendKeys and pass in a variable

```vb
If f_GetAccessFieldValue("NINumber") <> "" Then
    strNINo = f_GetAccessFieldValue("NINumber")
    PbWindow("w_genapp_frame").PbWindow("Client Details").PbDataWindow("dw_ap010_03_02").SelectCell "#1","custp_ni_code"
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WshShell.SendKeys strNINo
    WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
End If
```